# Python code runs interactively but not when run as script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and have looked at similar questions but none seems to offer a solution to my simple case so I suspect I have made a basic error.  I am using Python 2.7 on a Mac and on Ubuntu running on a Chromebook. When the project is complete I shall transfer it to a Raspberry Pi.

This snippet of code runs without a problem if I invoke the interpreter with the python call and type in the code.

```
switch = (int(time.strftime("%M"))%2
WhichOne = "Right","Left"
usbname = WhichOne[switch]
```

However, when I run the script containing this code fragment by typing ./project20160218.py or 
python project20160218.py

I obtain

```
 user@chrubuntu:~/Documents/Degree day project$ python project20160218.py
  File "project20160218.py", line 23
  WhichOne = "Right","Left"
       ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I would be very grateful for some guidance here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in the first line just before %2:

```
switch = (int(time.strftime("%M")))%2
WhichOne = "Right","Left"
usbname = WhichOne[switch]
```

If you close that it works. Also I assume you're importing time elsewhere, otherwise that would be undefined and also cause issues.

Comment: Tom. Would you explain why?  I see three opening and three closing brackets.  In fact I could remove the outer pair I believe.

Comment: In the question there are 3 opening parentheses and 2 closing parentheses on that first line. That imbalance creates a syntax error when you try to set the WhichOne variable.

It's worth noting that your example didn't run in the interpreter when I ran it myself until I fixed that, so if balancing the parentheses still doesn't fix your issue then please let us know.

Comment: You are right.  I was looking at the code included with your answer not the code that I submitted.  Thank you.  I am surprised that the syntax error did not occur at the level of that statement rather than with the following line.